# How to figure out if something started, on a timeline

Tags: javascript, algorithm, audio, video

I'm moving a play head shown below with *orange* color. There are multiple audio clips shown in *green*, *light blue*, *dark blue*, and *gray* colors.

[image: Parallel things]

While moving the play head, when an audio clip is encountered, I would play it.

Consider this pseudo-code:

```js
playhead.callbackForEveryFrame(doStuffOnEveryFrame)

function doStuffOnEveryFrame(t) {
    // I intend to make sure all clips which should be playing, are actually play!
    if (clip_green.startTime < t) {
        clip_green.play()
    }
    if (clip_lightblue.startTime < t) {
        clip_lightblue.play()
    }
    if (clip_darkblue.startTime < t) {
        clip_darkblue.play()
    }
    if (clip_gray.startTime < t) {
        clip_gray.play()
    }
}
```

The above code is inefficient. Since it's calling `play` continuously, if `t` is larger than a clip's `startTime`.

But it's preferred to call `play` just once, exactly when `t` crosses the `startTime`.

I have a hard time finding the best approach to detect when `t` crosses the `startTime` of each audio clip. Does anybody have any suggestion?

Comment: So the purpose is that multiple clips could be playing at the same time?

Comment: A good approach is to sort your start times once. Then, have a variable that holds the first next start time that hasn't been reached yet. As you go forward you check to see if you have reached this time, and if you have just load the next closest time. This is a sort and pointer approach.

Comment: @trincot That's right :)

Comment: @user1984 Thanks, let me try it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your pseudo code to something like this:

```
let events = [clip_green, clip_lightblue, clip_darkblue, clip_gray].flatMap(clip => [
    { time: clip.start_time, do: () => clip.play() }, 
    { time: clip.end_time,   do: () => clip.stop() }
]).sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time)

playhead.callbackForEveryFrame(doStuffOnEveryFrame)

function doStuffOnEveryFrame(t) {
    while (events.length && events[0].time < t) events.shift().do()
}
```

To avoid that this callback is called even when all is done, you would need a function to stop listening to frame changes. Something like:

```
function doStuffOnEveryFrame(t) {
    while (events.length && events[0].time < t) events.shift().do()
    if (!events.length) playhead.stopCallbackForEveryFrame(doStuffOnEveryFrame);
}
```